# Delete non-default Module in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I tried to use Module following this tutorial

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/

I need to delete Module quickly.

my cronjob-module.yaml is

```
application: myappication
module: cronjob-module
version: uno
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
```

Please tell me how to do it?

Comment: Anyone know if there's a simple way to do this in batch, i.e. delete **all** non-default versions of **all** modules?

Answer (score 11):

You can easily delete a non-default module in the developer console.  Click on Versions, then use the "Module:" pulldown to select the name of your module 'cronjob-module', then delete the versions you want.

If you have more than one version, the default version will say, "cannot delete default version".  But delete the others first, and hit "stop" on the default version.  Then, you get the "Delete" button clickable.  I believe if you do it in that order, you can delete all of the versions.

Comment: thanks, but i cannot find the delete button. Plz see the capture https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27576887/StackOverFlow/1.JPG

Comment: You are on "Dashboard".  Click on "Versions"

Answer (score 2):

Using gcloud: see list of modules and their versions, then delete with module name and version number

```
gcloud preview app modules list

gcloud preview app modules delete your-module-name --version 0.0.0
```

More:
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/preview/app/modules/delete?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Some of `gcloud` APIs have changed. So use the following from now on.

1. List all `versions` in all `services` (including `default`):

   ```
   gcloud preview app versions list
   ```
2. Stop a specific version:

   ```
   gcloud preview app versions stop 20160421t052824
   ```
3. Delete a specific version:

   ```
   gcloud preview app versions delete 20160421t052824
   ```
4. **Delete an entire service** (*this is what you want):

   ```
   gcloud preview app services delete api
   ```